# SharePoint 2010 List Form Error

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, infopath, error

I am using Microsoft Designer and Infopath on SharePoint 2010. This morning, I was able to submit the new entries to the list via the form with no issues. This afternoon, it suddenly is not working and is giving me the following error:

"The form cannot be submitted because it contains validation errors. Errors are marked with either a red asterisk (required fields) or a red, dashed border (invalid values). Field or group: my:Title Error: Cannot be blank"

Not only do I not have any required fields, but I also do not have any fields with the word "Title" in them. In fact, I don't even know of anywhere on this form where anything even has a label box called a "title".

I have searched all over the internet for an answer to this and have decided that one does not yet exist.

Is there anyone out there who can translate this error message and explain what needs to be done to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

All SharePoint Lists have Title columns that are set to required by default. Open your list and click on List settings. Then go to Advanced Settings. Then click on the first option to manage content types. When you go back to List settings you should now see a content type listed in the middle section. Click on it. There will either be an option to see the fields for that content type or they will be showing. (Sorry not in front of my computer at the moment and writing this off my memory) click on the Title column and make it optional. You will then be all set.